# How to set Focus on top Item?

Tags: android-layout

I have one scroll view and but while I am running the code I found that some items in top are hides.
I want to show this scroll view from top most. please help me.
code is here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:scrollX="0px">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

         <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_logo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:focusable="true" 
            android:layout_marginTop="1dip" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_logo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/jvdbanner" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/main_list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="279dip"
            android:background="#84CFE7"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:divider="#000000"
            android:dividerHeight="1dip"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:fadingEdge="none"
            android:scrollbars="none" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:background="#ffffff" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:text="Copyright @ 2012- JVD Properties, Inc."
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:text="All Rights Reserved."
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="13sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just Try this code..hope it works for you

```
final ScrollView main = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);

    main.post(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            main.scrollTo(0,0);
        }
    });
```